# Inversing rotation of one axis in relation to a parent bone

Tags: rigging

I have a mesh that has 2 heads. I want to rig the mesh in a way that;

- when I rotate the main head on the Y and X axis, the second head rotates in identical direction
- when I rotate in the Z axis I want the rotation of the second head be inversed, so that the heads turn to face each other

What is the most practical way of achieving this type of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a *Copy Rotation* constraint, you need to enable all the *Axis* and also enable the *Invert* axis for the one that is supposed to be symmetrical. Also choose the right *Target* and *Owner* spaces:

[image]

[image]